# How to convert little endian float binary to time format

Tags: python, endianness

I'm trying to read a (.SKD) file that is written in little endian binary. I did open the file and select/print the 4 bytes that represent the time stamp which I'm interested of converting to the form of HH:MM

example of bytes I have:
26, 231, 215, 85
148, 20, 216, 85
90, 253, 215, 85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import struct
import datetime

def convert(timestamp):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

def binary_to_int(b):
    return struct.unpack('<i', b)[0] # read string as little endian integer

sampledata = [26, 231, 215, 85]
binarydata = struct.pack('<BBBB', *sampledata)
timestamp = binary_to_int(binarydata)
result = convert(timestamp)
```

the struct module is used to read binary as little endian

for more information:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html